# second variation of the action for 1-d lagrangian

Tags: variational-principle

i know that the first variation of the action integral yields to the euler lagrange equation by setting $ \delta S [y(x)]=0 $

however given a Lagrangian in the form $$ \frac{1}{2}mv^ {2}-V(x)$$

how can i get the second variation $ \delta ^{2} S[y(X)]=0 $ ? for this lagrangian.

Comment: Why you want to do the second variation? The first variation suffices for the purpose of figuring out the equations of motion. The second variation is evaluated to tell whether your critical function is minimum, maximum or saddle (which does not matter here). Any way here's a useful read for you: (http://www.math.umn.edu/~olver/ln_/cv.pdf). Start reading from the section entitled "4. The Second Variation".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about setting the second variation to zero but I too have asked this question, here is what I got. 
\begin{equation}
\delta ^2A_0=\delta A(q_0+\delta q)-\delta A(q_0)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=\int ^{t_f}_{t_i}\bigg[-m(\ddot q_0+\delta \ddot{q})-\nabla V(q_0+\delta q)\bigg]\delta qdt-\int ^{t_f}_{t_i}\bigg[-m\ddot q_0-\nabla V(q_0)\bigg]\delta qdt
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=\int ^{t_f}_{t_i}\bigg[-m\delta \ddot q-\nabla ^2V(q_0)\delta q\bigg]\delta qdt
\end{equation}
With $\frac{\partial (\nabla V)}{\partial q}\delta q=\nabla ^2V\delta q$. 
I am confident that this is going to give the Jacobi field equation but I can't find the proof or do it myself sadly, what are your thoughts? The Jacobi field equation is obtained via Jacobi's variational problem,

\begin{equation}
m\delta \ddot{q}+\nabla ^2V=0
\end{equation}

Please see my question here which I am about to put up for [bounty](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/191584/lagrangian-perturbation-theory). Although entitled differently I think we are asking the same thing since we both require a general theory of second order variations?  :)